# gratulieren needs dative case, so why jmdn (accusatice)?

Tags: verb

As I know we use *gratulieren* with dative case, but in dictionary it is written like this:

> ohne OBJ ▪  jmd. gratuliert jmdm. (zu etwas *Dat.*) jmdn. aus einem bestimmten Anlass beglückwünschen

As you see there is a "jmdn." What does this accusative mean ? How use it ?

Comment: jmdn. refers to beglückwünschen, which takes the accusative and is used here in defining the lemma gratulieren. As for gratulieren, the dictionary you cite is clear enough: "jmd. gratuliert jmdm." IOW: ich beglückwünsche dich zu etwas OR ich gratuliere dir zu etwas.

Comment: Comparing apples with oranges usually doesn't lead to good comprehension of either nature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up two verbs:

- ***gratulieren***
  This verb needs its object in dative case:

  > Sie gratuliert **ihm**.
  >   *In Engl.: She congratulates him. She compliments him.*

  - *Sie*
    Subjekt, Nominativ
  - *gratuliert*
    Verb
  - *ihm*
    Objekt, **Dativ**
- ***beglückwünschen***
  This verbs needs its object in accusative case:

  > Sie beglückwünscht **ihn**.
  >   *In Engl.: She congratulates him. She compliments him.*

  - *Sie*
    Subjekt, Nominativ
  - *beglückwünscht*
    Verb
  - *ihn*
    Objekt, **Akkusativ**

---

The entry in your dictionary says:

> The phrase *"jmd. gratuliert jmdm."* means the same as the phrase *"jmdn. beglückwünschen"*.

So you are comparing two different phrases with two different verbs, each of them needs its own kind of object.